# Telegram api prints 'Not a valid URI' when trying to post a url with #

Tags: spring-boot, telegram

I'm building a spring boot app that is utilizing Telegram api. I've used HTTP as the parseMode and I'm basically trying to send some details along with the link to find the details. The frontend is built using angular which uses HashLocationStrategy.

While sending the telegram message from backend, I include the url which has a '#' in it, so it goes like https://example.com/xyz/#/rest-of-the-url.
I've escaped all the percent encoding characters and the message gets printed correctly in console, but the telegram api is not allowing me to send it saying 'https://example.com/xyz/#/rest-of-the-url Not a valid URI'.

If I remove the # (basically by adding  in index.html, it works fine, but then the frontend doesn't work correctly after refresh after loading it on tomcat.

Below is the code snippet I am using to post messages to my telegram group,

```
public void sendMessage(String message, String chatID) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.out.println(message);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(tgBaseUrl+tgBotToken+"/sendMessage")
                .queryParam("chat_id", chatID)
                .queryParam("text", message)
                .queryParam("parse_mode", "HTML");
        ResponseEntity exchange = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString()
                .replaceAll("%20", " ")
                .replaceAll("%0A", "\n")
                .replaceAll("%3C", "<")
                .replaceAll("%3E", ">")
                .replaceAll("%7C", "|")
                .replaceAll("%3D", "=")
                .replaceAll("%23", "#"),
                HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
        logger.error("Error response : State code: {}, response: {} ", e.getStatusCode(), e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception err) {
        logger.error("Error: {} ", err.getMessage());
        throw new Exception("This service is not available at the moment!");
    }
}
```

Please help me out...

P.S. Also not being able to send emojis.. everything works perfectly when I post the same message including emojis from postman..